# Jquery change HTML attribute using attr() returns object object

Tags: javascript, jquery, attr

I have read multiple different articles and questions to no avail. I have a PHP page that will use AJAX to update an easypiechart using values from a database with a check every X minutes. In this example I have reduced the time to 10 seconds with an alert box to show what changes have been made.

I can use the attr() to view the "data-percent" however it returns "Object Object" if I attempt to change the value of the "data-percent" attribute.

I am trying to manually just change the value to 90 for the time being until I can get this function to work before adding the ajax response as the replacement.

code:

```
    <!-- Link to Google CDN's jQuery + jQueryUI; fall back to local -->
<div id="test" class="easy-pie-chart txt-color-blue easyPieChart" data-percent="38" data-pie-size="160">
    <span class="percent percent-sign txt-color-blue font-lg semi-bold"></span>
</div>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    if (!window.jQuery) {
        document.write('<script src="js/libs/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"><\/script>');
    }
</script>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script>
    if (!window.jQuery.ui) {
        document.write('<script src="js/libs/jquery-ui-1.10.3.min.js"><\/script>');
    }
</script>

<script>
// Setup AJAX request -->
function updateWidgets(){
    $.ajax({
      url: "widgetGet.php",
      type: "POST",
      success: function(data) {
        var response = $.parseJSON(data);
        var idea = parseInt(response.test);
        var ID = $("#test").attr("data-percent");
        var IDchange = $("#test").attr("data-percent", 90);
        alert(ID);
      }
    });
  }

  updateWidgets();
  setInterval(updateWidgets, 10000);
  </script>
```

If you switch the alert from ID to IDchange you can see where my problem is. Thanks guys as I know I am in the hands of a great community here.

Update, understandably the alert function shouldn't be used for debugging. What the issue (and not sure if attr()) is the solution is to update the html attribute using a AJAX response that is initiated every 10 seconds. Documentation such as [this](http://www.jquery-tutorial.net/dom-manipulation/getting-and-setting-attributes/) show that attributes are updated using the attr() which leads to my confusion.

In short, how can I update the html attribute of the div containing the easypiechart using AJAX that is receiving data every 10 seconds?

Comment: well, yeah, that's what all jquery methods do when used as a setter. http://api.jquery.com/attr

Comment: This is why you shouldn't use `alert()` for debugging - it coerces everything to a string and it blocks the UI thread. Always use `console.log` or `console.dir`

Comment: The jQuery `.data()` method is, in my opinion, preferable to fooling with the attributes directly, though it's not exactly the same as doing so.

Comment: downside to .data() though of course is that it has a lot more overhead, compared to just altering/reading attributes. I prefer .attr

Comment: @KevinB I think `data()` is still much faster than accessing the DOM. Sadly jsperf.com is no longer with us so I can't look it up quickly.

Comment: I believe it is faster, after the first usage and for repeated usage. just not so much if you're reading the attribute value once and never again. This though appears to be a case of the former, so .data does make sense.

Comment: much appreciated for your comments, everyone. I am not fluent in javascript in comparison to PHP, therefore it was poor form to use this for debugging purposes. What I want to do is use AJAX to update this attribute (and many others) within a dashboard which will have a number of attributes that need to be updated on a regular basis. When using the above code it was not directly changing the attribute (hance no change to the graph) when a new value was received via AJAX.

Comment: Would anyone have any ideas of best practices to make direct updates to attributes using AJAX to the code provided above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reading a ton of articles I found the answer which was easypiecharts itself. The JS associated to easypiecharts will touch on the data attribute. Reading the documentation of easypiecharts I found the answer:

```
$('#test').data('easyPieChart').update(90); //to update the chart to 90%
```

My problem was the direction to solve the problem as a ton of articles were referencing the attr() function. For my scenario, the attr() function wouldn't  update the chart (nor prop() unless the chart was refreshed to visually see the update). Those articles were referencing this function on an element that isn't associated with other external JS files.

Thanks everyone for your contribution and I learnt some important lessons today. I hope someone finds this answer helpful for anyone wanting to work with AJAX and easypiecharts with dynamic percentage updates.

Answer (score 3):

The `.attr()` function returns the jQuery object when it's invoked with two arguments. In other words, you get back the value of `$("#test")`.

It does that so you can do things like

```
$("#test").attr("foo", "bar").hide();
```

If you want to see the value *after* the change, then:

```
var IDchange = $("#test").attr("data-percent", 90).attr("data-percent");
```

Comment: @wick-12c Maybe you are not familiar with [Fluen Interface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface) and it can be useful to understand this answer I think :)

Comment: very good answer Pointy and would like to give you an upvote but I do not qualify for this yet. I noticed people were using the attr() to not only check but to also make changes to the attribute but I obviously had a misunderstanding to the function.

Comment: Ok I have made progress and have asked one of my developers at work (now that I am in the office). You cannot necessarily see a change in the source code and because we are making an update to an attribute that is related to easypiecharts I will need to read the documentation on the included scripts of easypiecharts to find a way to reload it after the above-mentioned change by @pointy.